# How to calculate how long users are using our app in android

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to know how we can calculate how long users are using my app and I want to reward them if he used my app for a particular time period. and then it should start again whenever the user gets out of the app and comes back. I got to know about UsageStatsManager, but the user should provide the permission but I don't want to do so... please tell me is there any method to do that so I can reward the user for using the app for x minutes. For example in games, they reward us some skins or guns for using their app for x number of minutes. I also want to do so.... so if you any method it would help me a lot!

And thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the Calendar class

```
import java.util.Calendar

Date currentTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
```

then save the current time when your user opens their app

```
@Override
public void onActivityStarted(Activity activity) {
      //record time here
}

@Override
public void onActivityStopped(Activity activity) {
     //get time recorded in onActivityStarted
     //use it to figure out duration of app used here and then post it to your api or save it to a local database
}
```

Article on detecting when a user enters foreground /background

https://medium.com/@iamsadesh/android-how-to-detect-when-app-goes-background-foreground-fd5a4d331f8a

You could check that time you recorded in a multitude of locations though, so if you didn't want to just check when the user backgrounded it, you could check the progress wherever you want, depending on how you saved the initial time they started.